# How does different bean scopes work on the server?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I wonder how applying the different bean scopes in CDI (`@ApplicationScoped`, `@SessionScoped` and `@RequestScoped`) works. I understand the life cycle, but where in the container are these stored? I am using these annotations on JSF beans.

How are these beans stored on the server and how is the server capable of knowing which beans belong to who.

For example is a bean that have a `@SessionScoped` stored in the `HTTPSession` object behind the scenes? Are beans with `@ApplicationScoped` stored in a map instance variable in `ServletContext`? If so, what about thread safety. I guess I have misunderstood it but it would be great if somebody could teach me what happens, where they are stored (the different scopes), how is the server capable of knowing which beans belongs to who...like are there any other ids (not only session id)?

I am btw using Java EE 6 all Reference Implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example is a bean that has an @SessionScoped stored in the HTTPSession object behind the scenes? Are beans with @ApplicationScoped stored in a map instance variable in the ServletContext?

For the web layer, that is indeed what happens. If the bean has been instantiated you can often find it back there by manually iterating over all objects in said maps.

`@RequestScoped` is a special thing though. In the web layer this corresponds with the request attribute map, but this scope also applies to calls to e.g. remote session beans, or message driven beans processing a message. In that case, there is no http request and hence no request attribute map. It's likely that those are stored 'somewhere else', probably in TLS (Thread Local Storage) that's set and unset by the bean proxy.

> If so, what about thread safety.

Application- and Session scoped beans are by themselves simply not thread safe. **You** have to take care of thread-safety, for instance by using thread-safe data structures, the synchronized keyword, or a bean type that's inherently thread-safe (like a @Stateful annotated bean).

Comment: Ok, so there is no more "hocus pocus" to it than that :) But, I understand that `@ApplicationScoped` AKA ServletContext is not threadsafe because multiple clients could try to change it at the same time...but why isn't `@SessionScoped` thread safe? Isn't it just one client who have access to the same bean?

Comment: For `SessionScoped` there is virtually no limit to how many requests may simultaneously access it. Of course, they typically all originate from the same client. Think multiple windows, multiple tabs or multiple AJAX requests coming from the same window.

Comment: Ok, then you mentioned if a bean is inherently thread-safe such as the EJBs (some types at least)...then you mean that it is kept as a property of a bean used in JSF right?